# Change message with a random system (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a bot for discord (using discord.js), and I tried to make a system that says "It's me Mario" when you say "; its-me", and a small chance to send only "It's me" and with a photo of "Golden Freddy" (FNAF), I wanted to make the message "bug" and as I said earlier the photo of Golden Freddy appears. It worked at first, but it didn't bug the text. How do I solve this?
Sorry if I wrote something wrong I am using google translator

Code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    name: "its-me",
    description: "Mario meme",

    async run (client, message, args) {

        var list = [
           //? 
        ]

        var rand = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];

        const mario = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`It's me!`)
        .setImage('https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mario-bros/images/7/75/Mario.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/340?cb=20131012013704&path-prefix=pt-br')
        .setColor("RED");

        const golden = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`ıɬ'ʂm̸̩̙̖̝̣̻̈́̈̃̀͑̂̾͝e̸̼̪͂̈́̀̇̈́̕  !`)
        .setImage(`https://i.pinimg.com/originals/43/e2/7a/43e27a96c3d58e32907ded73134c2faf.png`)
        .setColor('#B8860B')

        message.channel.send(rand)
    }
}
```